# how to post image with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
<p className="key">Şəkil <span className="makeRed">*</span></p> <div className="value valueFile"><button className="uploadImg"><input  className="fileUpload" type="file"  placeholder="Şəkil yükləyin"/> <p>Şəkil yükləyin</p> </button> </div>
<p className="key"></p> <div className="value"><p className="key"></p> <div className="value">JPG , PNG</div></div>
```

In here  i want to post image but i dont know how to post ,  any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can import an image from your src folder:

```
import myImage from "./mypath/myImage.jpeg";
```

And use it in an img tag as src attribute:

`<img src={myImage} alt="a description to my image"/>`

Comment: No man i dont want to show image i want to post image with react to api

Comment: You don't really need hooks for that. Here you can find some info on how to upload a file:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects